# In Apache Solr DataImport Getting this Error: "Unable to execute query"

Tags: php, apache, solr

```
 <dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
     driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb"
     user="root"
     password="root"
    />
    <document name="bestsellerscats_1">
       <entity name="bestsellerscats" query="SELECT id, name FROM testtable">
          <field column="id" name="id"/>
          <field column="name" name="name"/>
       </entity>
    </document>
  </dataConfig>
```

This is the error message:

> Exception while processing: bestsellerscats document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT id, name FROM testtable Processing Document # 1

Any Help?

Comment: I have figured out the solution, there was the issue with the MySql connection which is getting refused 

By Default MySQL Tcp socket connection is false due to security need to bind the local ip address for localhost 

find the my.cnf file in server for mysql configuration which is located in "opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf" find "[mysqld]
" and comment the skip-networking "# skip-networking" and put this "bind-address=127.0.0.1" and restart the mysql

In my case its worked...!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your url. Try to maintain the following format.

```
jdbc:mysql://<ip>:<port>/<myDB>
```

In your case you need to have, if you are using the default mysql port.

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
```